# Iterate array of integer in c

Tags: c, arrays

I programmed the next code in c.

What have i done wrong:

```
int *ip;
int i;
ip = (int*) malloc(5*sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  ip[i]=i;
}
```

When I run over the code with the debugger it's like I'm not iterating over IP.

Could someone help?

Comment: how you can tell you are not iterating over ip? (also in C you don't cast result of malloc)

Comment: The code is correct. Print the content of ip the check. Your interpretation of the debugger output might be wrong. To me the problem is between the chair and the computer.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: `it's like I'm not iterating over IP.`...kindly let us know the reason behind this conclusion. Till time, voted UWYA.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , What is "UWYA"?

Comment: @CoolGuy "unclear what you're asking" :-)

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` and also to check whether `ip` is a null pointer after `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

its works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     int *ip;
     int i;
     ip = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));

     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
         ip[i]=i;
     }

     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
          printf(" %d ",ip[i]);
      }
      free(ip);
      return 0;
}
```

out put `0 1 2 3 4`

Comment: "*Standard Warning : Please do not cast the return value of malloc() and family.*"

Comment: Also, free the memory after the use and check the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem as follows: when you walk though the program step-by-step using the debugger, you cannot see it running the loop 5 times.

The reason may lie in the optimizations performed by the C compiler, especially **loop unrolling**.

If you use gcc, try the option `-O0` to avoid optimizations. This may help debugging.